# Running a PHP script in Crontab (cPanel) that triggers another script via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cron

I'm trying to run a .PHP script at 15 minutes intervals, via my cPanel on shared hosting.

So far I managed to get the script done, which works perfectly in the browser.
But when I try to run it in crontab, it doesn't work.

Basically, my main .PHP script called **audiojungle.php** gets some data via AJAX call from a server that has API functions, and if certain conditions are OK, it triggers a local AJAX call to another script called **send_mail.php**,
which sends a mail to a local mailbox on my shared hosting, which finally gets forwarded to me on my main Gmail account.

Basically I check if I got a sale on Envato market AudioJungle, using Envato.com API functions.

So far everything works wonderful directly in the browser...and also I managed to trigger the cron to execute the script like this

/usr/local/bin/php /home/cubeworx/public_html/cron/audiojungle.php

I also set the mail address in crontab to see if something's happening,
and what I get in that email is the generated source HTML from my "audiojungle.PHP" script.

I'm a newbie in working with cron, I know generally how it works, but I don't know what it means when I get the HTML generated by my PHP script back. Does it mean it worked ?
Sadly, no. Because it should trigger my AJAX call that sends the mail with
"hey you got a new sale!" and it doesn't.

Is there something I'm missing here ?

Code is perfectly working in browser so it definitely is something that is connected to the way cron works and I'm not aware of.

Anyone who could help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

---

edit (after successfully completing the script)

- everything needs to be done in .PHP (so no Javascript), as CRON in Linux does execute the PHP parser, which has to have only PHP in it so it can run flawlessly. PHP parser doesn't read Javascript. So to access my API I had to use cUrl to get the valid answer from the API (not AJAX), and then parse the answer as JSON (the API was returning a JSON type of answer).

This edit is for the people that would be interested in my question, so they know how I resolved it. Cheers

Comment: Your PHP is doing AJAX to get more PHP?  Why wouldn't you handle that entirely in PHP?

Comment: my main .PHP script contains Javascript that does AJAX call to get JSON from Envato's website API (where I work as freelancer audio producer) and then checks the JSON received, and if it notices recent (less than 15 minutes) sale there, it opens another AJAX call to use PHPMailer functions to send mail. I cannot send mail from Javascript

Comment: You're going to need to use [their PHP API](https://github.com/Japh/Envato-Marketplace-API-Wrapper-in-PHP) directly.  When running as a cron you're not going to be able to use javascript.  [See this SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093997/it-is-possible-to-use-ajax-jquery-page-with-cron)